# how to change the format date of the placeHolder of a formControl type date in react-bootstap

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I use react-bootstrap and the `formControl` of type date.

```
     <Form.Control
          type="date"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={ChangeDate}
          min={minDateISO}
          max={maxDateISO}
          className="select-class"           
        />
```

when I display my component it is displayed with a placeHolder of type `"jj/mm/aaaa"` but I would like when I change languages ​​via i18n language that the placeHolder automatically changes format to pass to this format `"dd/mm/yyyy"` same when I display the datePicker for the texts "delete" and "Today"

is there a possibility to change the internationalization of the placeHolder and the datePicker?